# Aumentar valor de un input de 10% en 10%

Tags: javascript, html, api

Tengo un html que tiene como funcionar mostrar el total a pagar y el abono min que debe hacer. en donde el valor min del abono es el 50% del total lo que necesito es que si se clickea como las flechas que tiene un input estas aumenten o disminuyan de 10% en 10% respetando que no se puede reducir mas del 50% del total y no puede pasar mas del 100% que va a corresponder al total. este es mi código.
HTML

```
{% if precio_departamento %}
   <label for="abono">Total a Abonar</label>
   <input type="number" id="abono" name="abono" required>  
{% else %}
   <p>No se encontró información del departamento.</p>
{% endif %}

<label for="total">Total a pagar:</label>
<input type="number" id="total" name="total" required readonly>
```

este es mi js

```
function formatDate(date) {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1; 
    let day = date.getDate();

    month = month < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;
    day = day < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;

    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

const precioBaseInicial = document.getElementById('precio');
const precioTexto = precioBaseInicial.textContent;
const precioNumerico = parseFloat(precioTexto.replace("CLP $", ""));

function actualizarTotal() {
    const fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById('inicio').value);
    const fechaTermino = new Date(document.getElementById('termino').value);
    const unDia = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    const diferenciaDias = Math.round((fechaTermino - fechaInicio) / unDia);

    const checkbox = document.getElementById("transporte");
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('comboboxTrans');
    const selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex];
    const tarifaAdicional = parseFloat(selectedOption.getAttribute('data-tarifa'));

    const checkbox2 = document.getElementById("tour");
    const selectElement2 = document.getElementById('comboboxTour');
    const selectedOption2 = selectElement2.options[selectElement2.selectedIndex];
    const tarifaAdicional2 = parseFloat(selectedOption2.getAttribute('data-tarifa'));

    let nuevoTotal;

    if (checkbox.checked && checkbox2.checked) {
      nuevoTotal = (precioNumerico * diferenciaDias) + tarifaAdicional + tarifaAdicional2;
    } else if (checkbox.checked) {
      nuevoTotal = (precioNumerico * diferenciaDias) + tarifaAdicional;
    } else if (checkbox2.checked) {
      nuevoTotal = (precioNumerico * diferenciaDias) + tarifaAdicional2;
  } else {
      nuevoTotal = precioNumerico * diferenciaDias;
  }
    document.getElementById('total').value = nuevoTotal;

    const abono = Math.floor(nuevoTotal / 2);
    document.getElementById('abono').value = abono;
}
```

El total se calcula con un valor fijo después obtenemos la diferencia entre los días de inicio reserva y termino reserva para luego multiplicarlo por el valor fijo. después de eso obtenemos el valor del 50% del total que se guarda en el input abono. la duda que tengo es como aumentar o disminuir de 10% en 10% sin disminuir mas del 50% y sin aumentar mas del 100% en el input abono.

Comment: [_¿Step_?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step)